# I'm getting error for creating react-app.what to do to solve this error?

Tags: reactjs, npm, web, npm-install, project

I was writing in my vs code terminal:

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

and getting this error.

```
PS E:\react> npx create-react-app my-app
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\username~1\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_cacache\tmp\07cf48de
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Users\username~1\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_cacache\tmp\07cf48de'
npm ERR!  [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Users\username~1\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_cacache\tmp\07cf48de'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'open',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Users\\Nabanita~1\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm-cache\\


_cacache\\tmp\\07cf48de'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Log files were not written due to an error writing to the directory: C:\Users\username~1\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs
npm ERR! You can rerun the command with `--loglevel=verbose` to see the logs in your terminal
PS E:\react>
```

i have tried all these command but nothing works for me.

```
npm install -g create-react-app    
npx create-react-app my-app     
cd my-app      
npm start
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using sudo:

```
sudo npx create-react-app my-app
```

It seems like you may be having permission issues.

Comment: thank u for ur reply but it's showing some error.

Answer (score 0):

Seems permission issue

1: Try opening the Powershell or cmd as Administrator

2: Next, try `npm cache clean --force`

3: For immediate fix, you may use yarn

```
npm install -g yarn
yarn create react-app my-app
```

Comment: nothing is working still getting error. Thank u for your solution

Comment: error is same or something has changed? Can you try reinstalling latest node